# Creating table with different columns depending on condition (which is SQL version)

Tags: sql, sql-server, dbcc

I would like to create a table for statement: `DBCC CHECKDB (0) WITH ALL_ERRORMSGS, TABLERESULTS` however the result of this statement depends on SQL Server version, in higher versions there are more columns.

Statement:

```
IF (CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('productversion') AS varchar), 2) > '10'    
    CREATE TABLE #dbcc_output (columns..)
ELSE        
    CREATE TABLE #dbcc_output (different columns..)
```

This code causes an error:

> There is already an object named '#dbcc_output' in the database

Is there a smart way to do it or just check if object exists in ELSE part?

Comment: This is a parsing error, you can't try to create the same object in the same batch more than once, even if it is *impossible* for both statements to be run.

Comment: Why not just create a table will all the columns you need, regardless of the version? Then you don't need to try and create 2 different versions.

Comment: If you're doing something like this `INSERT #dbcc_output (..) EXEC ('DBCC CHECKDB (mydb) WITH ALL_ERRORMSGS, TABLERESULTS')`, which requires the exact columns, then you'll need to create your temp table and run the DBCC together with dynamic SQL.

Comment: Or drop support for SQL 2008, which is no longer supported by Microsoft.